# How to remove debugging symbols in firebase .so files?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using firebase plugin for unity project which includes remoteConfig, Crashlytic, analytic. There some debugging symbols in firebase .so files on android apk:
example in file ./lib/armeabi-v7a/libFirebaseCppApp-10_1_1.so:
[…snip…]

00218406 W ZNSt6__ndk110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore14PromiseFactoryINS3_18WriteBatchInternal7AsyncFnEED1EvEUlRNS3_17FirestoreInternalEE_NS_9allocatorISA_EEFvS9_EEclES9

00219672 W _ZNSt6__ndk110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore14PromiseFactoryINS3_25DocumentReferenceInternal7AsyncFnEEC1EPNS3_17FirestoreInternalEEUlRS8_E_NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvSA_EE18destroy_deallocateEv

00219670 W _ZNSt6__ndk110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore14PromiseFactoryINS3_25DocumentReferenceInternal7AsyncFnEEC1EPNS3_17FirestoreInternalEEUlRS8_E_NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvSA_EE7destroyEv

002195fc W _ZNSt6__ndk110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore14PromiseFactoryINS3_25DocumentReferenceInternal7AsyncFnEEC1EPNS3_17FirestoreInternalEEUlRS8_E_NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvSA_EED0Ev

00219676 W ZNSt6__ndk110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore14PromiseFactoryINS3_25DocumentReferenceInternal7AsyncFnEEC1EPNS3_17FirestoreInternalEEUlRS8_E_NS_9allocatorISB_EEFvSA_EEclESA

[…snip…]

=> So i want to remove debugging symbols in libFirebaseCppApp-10_1_1.so for security. How can i do that? Thanks.

Remove debugging symbols in firebase .so files

Comment: is there a non debug version to download?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.